# Rasberrypi 4 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.uix.picker'

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, raspberry-pi4

My program was successfully installed all the package from Windows 10 and was able to run the code. But when I transfer the program from the rasberrypi 4 using Thonny IDE I got some errors of this.

```
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDTimePicker
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.uix.picker'
>>> 
Backend terminated or disconnected. Use 'Stop/Restart' to restart.
```

I already follow these steps https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/timepicker/ but I still got an error on my end. Is there a way I could install this package on rasberrypi 4 ubuntu the "kivymd.uix.picker"? Thank you

Comment: cross check your python version and check if you've installed kivymd properly using pip(or pip3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDTimePicker

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).